# Changing CLASSPATH to JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.12.jar, java command stops working

Tags: java, junit-rule

When I change my `CLASSPATH` variable to `JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.12.jar` in system variables, my Java command stops working.

For example, when I want to execute a class file I get the error "*Could not find or load main class*", though `javac` is working fine.

When I remove the `CLASSPATH`, the `java` command starts working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CLASSPATH` variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes. When you execute a java command to start a Java application, it start a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and calling that class's main method.

If your `CLASSPATH` variable is set to `JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.12.jar`, only classes inside the `JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.12.jar` will be loaded. Therefore, you will get a `Could not find or load main class` error.

The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the `-cp` command line switch. This allows the `CLASSPATH` to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications.

The default value of the class path is `"."`, meaning that only the current directory is searched. If you want also find classes file in other directory, say classes in `c:\otherDirectory`, you can set the class path to the following:

```
java -classpath ".;c:\otherDirectory"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more jars that need to go on the classpath? 
JUNIT is for test purposes only and I would guess that you need to add all the dependencies you are using also on the classpath.
On the other hand it is not a good idea to do this through system environment variables. Please also look at the `java -classpath` command then you can add classpath dependencies for one application or command.